# How can i install antd propertly to use?

Tags: reactjs, antd

i installed antd to frontend of my app, i have this at the app.jsx

```
import "antd/dist/antd.css"
import { Button } from 'antd'
```

and now in my first component i am trying to use like this:

```
import antd from 'antd'
const { Card } = antd
```

but now i am getting this error

> [plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to resolve import
> "antd/es/default/style" from ".../component.jsx". Does the file exist?
> .../component.jsx:1:9 1  |  import 'antd/es/default/style';;import
> RefreshRuntime from "/@react-refresh";    |          ^

in node_modules there is not have the default 'ant/es/default' folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have installed everything correctly to your node_modules folder (e.g.   `npm install` or `yarn install`) you should be able to import either `antd/dist/antd.css` or if you just want to have the styles for the inputs `antd/es/input/style/index.css`